# Need MySQL query to update/add record into table1 from table2

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I want MySQL query to update/Add table1 if data exist in table2

If record not exist in table1 than add record (from table2)
otherwise update it.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Please show us the tried code bu you.

Comment: Use `Insert into` refer this link http://blogs.coldbuffer.com/inserting-or-updating-records-using-mysql-replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy all entries from table2 to table1 using the following syntax, assuming ID is the primary key of the tables:

```
INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM table1);
```

The Update-Query is not so generic:

```
UPDATE table1 SET <COL>=(SELECT <COL> FROM table2 WHERE table1.ID=table2.ID);
```

You'll have to perform the above update query for each Column in your tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE <condition>)) 
begin 
UPDATE table1
SET <specify new value>
end
else 
begin 
INSERT INTO table1
SELECT <column list> from table2 where <condition>
end
```